# Snowflake convert execute immediate to stored procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have multiple execute immediate statements and want to convert them into 1 stored procedure... however I been getting errors when trying to do this.  Is there some syntax adjustments I'd need to make to accomodate ?

```
execute immediate $$
declare
firstdbid NUMBER default (select min(db_sqid) from DIMENSIONS.DBMETA.DATABASES_STAGING where server_id = 320);
currdbid NUMBER default :firstdbid;
lastdbid NUMBER default (select max(db_sqid) from DIMENSIONS.DBMETA.DATABASES_STAGING where server_id = 320);

begin
    while (currdbid < lastdbid+1) do
    CALL DIMENSIONS.DBMETA.LOAD_SCHEMAS(SELECT DATABASE_NAME FROM DIMENSIONS.DBMETA.DATABASES_STAGING WHERE DB_SQID = :currdbid and server_id = 320);
    currdbid := currdbid+1;
    end while;
end;
$$



execute immediate $$
declare
firstdbid NUMBER default (select min(db_sqid) from DIMENSIONS.DBMETA.DATABASES_STAGING where server_id = 320);
currdbid NUMBER default :firstdbid;
lastdbid NUMBER default (select max(db_sqid) from DIMENSIONS.DBMETA.DATABASES_STAGING where server_id = 320);

begin
    while (currdbid < lastdbid+1) do
    CALL DIMENSIONS.DBMETA.LOAD_TABLES(SELECT DATABASE_NAME FROM DIMENSIONS.DBMETA.DATABASES_STAGING WHERE DB_SQID = :currdbid and server_id = 320);
    currdbid := currdbid+1;
    end while;
end;
$$
```

Comment: Please update your question with a) the SP code you've managed to write b) the command/parameters you're using to call the SP and c) the error messages you've been getting